# Laravel 9 - task scheduler controller function

Tags: php, laravel, cron, controller

Hello i'm looking on how to execute a controller function with a cronjob. I've read the documentation but it doesn't explain on how to call a controller function.

I have this function:

```
    function oracle(Request $request)  
{
    // some get-insert statements using DB Facade
}
```

Let's say i want to run this function every 10 minutes for each db record that has status = 0

then in laravel scheduler something like:

```
     $schedule->call(function () {
       //.. DB query to check all orders that have status = 0
       //.. for each record that returns 0
       //.. execute oracle()
       }
    })->everyMinute();
```

Basically all orders with status 0 are on mysql, now the oracle() logic triggers on a manual click. This function gets data from mysql and inserts to the oracle database. Once the record is on oracle it returns status 1 to mysql. I have to do this with a cron.

Which way should i go for?

Comment: create a `trait` having a common code of controller and cronjob and import that in both classes.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Bhaumik that the problem is not how to call a controller method. It is that you should not call a controller method from other places. So the code should be extraced. Maybe a trait, maybe a job/action.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Service Layer in your application to do this. Nice example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41937094/11251946).

You must:

- Move logic from Controller to Service
- Call this service in Controller
- Call this service in sheduler.

Comment: maybe it's not the best practice, but i created a command and insert the controller's logic in the handle() method. Everything seems working fine! Thank you so much!